# Unable to display flash message in view with ejs template

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

I am a newbie in NodeJS. I have a problem that I am unable to show flash message in my view.
Here is my Controller,

```
index : function(req, res){
    res.locals.flash = _.clone(req.session.flash);
    res.locals.layout = false;
    res.view('login');
},
login : function(req, res){

       ....

        if(!admin){
            req.session.flash = {
                err : 'User is not found.' // My flash message
            }
            res.locals.layout = false;
            res.redirect('login'); 
            return;
        }

      .....
}
```

Here is my view,

```
    <% if(flash && flash.err) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <% JSON.stringify(flash.err) %>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

When login is false, it show only an empty alert box. 
And I have a second problem. When I refresh page, The alert box isn't disappeared.

Could someone help me please.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alert box keeps on appearing because the `req.session.flash` object persists the session, so you need to null that out once it's used, or you can just simply use `req.flash()`, which does that for you. So change your `index` method to something like this:

```
index: function(req, res) {
    // req.flash() returns the contents of req.session.flash and flushes it
    // so it doesn't appear on next page load. No need to clone.
    res.locals.flash = req.flash();
    res.locals.layout = false;
    res.view('login');
},
```

Now, onto the second problem. The error messages aren't appearing because you aren't using the proper `EJS` syntax to output escaped values into the view. All you need to do is change your code to this:

```
<% if(flash && flash.err) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        // Change <% to <%=
        <%= flash.err %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

No need to JSON.stringify, unless you like the quotes. **Notice that I changed the `<%` to `<%=`**, which in EJS means "escape this and output it". It's not template HTML or anything like that, so it's okay to escape it anyway.